# .NET API AD authentication and authorization

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, active-directory

I’m working on an intranet application that uses .NET 6 as a backend API with an Angular front end I would like to authenticate the users using Active Directory that is hosted on-premise. I also want to keep the users in the MS SQL database connected to the .NET API and assign them roles/claims using the .NET API.

I can’t seem to find a solution/tutorial to accomplish a similar functionality and I would greatly appreciate your help and guidance in this matter.

Comment: Is the website hosted on-premises? Is the website's host PC connected to the on-premises Active Directory domain controllers?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Yes the website is hosted on-premise and in the same network as the Active Directory DC

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [Windows authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/) in the project properties in Visual Studio:

[image: Project Properties]

[image: Debug launch profiles]

And with the `/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication` element in the 'web.config' file (once the site is deployed to IIS):

```xml
<location path="Contoso">
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <authentication>
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
         </authentication>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

This enables *authentication*, not authorization. The currently logged-in user is mapped to the controller's 'User' property. From here, you can either implement a custom authorization filter, or map the user's groups to some claims (in a custom [ClaimsTransformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation?view=aspnetcore-7.0)) so that you can use the normal authorization policy pattern.

The claims principal is a `WindowsIdentity`, so if you need some windows-specific info you can cast the user:

```cs
var activeDirectoryUser = User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
```

Most of the important information is available through the principal's claims, so this should be pretty uncommon. If you need to look up the details of other users, you can use the following code:

```cs
using var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
var activeDirectoryUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);
```